# "Window snip" missing from Windows 10 screenshot utility

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I first used Windows 10 on my home PC, and as such I didn't even know window snip feature existed. This is what my <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> screenshot menu looks at home:

[image]

But at work I see:

[image]

Both systems are running Windows 10 Pro. Is there a hidden setting? Why can't I have window snip at home?

Comment: Are they different versions of Windows 10? There was a similar issue [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/snip-sketch-now-has-window-mode/f835328a-619f-49d5-ab8f-706066048d5a). I see Window snip on my 1909 and 1903 machines. On 1809 OS build 17763.1132 I do not see it.

Comment: Look for Snip 'n Sketch.  That is the new tool and you will find it in your Start Programs

Comment: @MC10 That's probably it, I see the same difference. Is this a matter of running windows update, or are these completely different versions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a setting I changed or it's just done this way but the major version update was not automatic. You may need to manually install the update for 1909: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMbnD.png

Comment: Edit your question and indicate what version of Windows 10 each machine is running

Comment: @MC10 Interesting. In the same menu, I can see a warning: "You’re currently running a version of Windows that’s nearing the end of service. We recommend you update to the most recent version of Windows 10 to get the latest features and security improvements." But I cannot see a button to download and install the update that can bee seen in your screenshot.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I guess that's a different question entirely but perhaps older versions are no longer supported and it's not getting the update. You should be able to manually download the update here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

This feature came later and this tool is updated by the Microsoft Store.

You can manually check for update directly [in the Microsoft Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026259/microsoft-store-get-updates-for-apps-and-games), and update "Snip & Sketch".

Comment: There is no update button for it in MS store. I can just see reviews, settings and the launch button.